# How to move one view controller to another view controller when we login with Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am beginner in iOS and in my project I have added Twitter login facility for users and after we click logged in the app with twitter  we get Twitter login page

Then user i click "Authorized App" button which is there in Twitter login page.
Then I want to move another view controller(i.e: main view controller to sub view controller) for this i have written some code but based on that code i can't move one main view controller to sub view controller

showing exception

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

## My Code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FHSTwitterEngine.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController ()<FHSTwitterEngineAccessTokenDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"yyp5D4Elbo4fBAdnbnOZDaPRt" andSecret:@"WwIfOHvw8j0rIlLPtBQiPZ5r1dl44X4Lh8H6rKY5gLb1m4YM72"];

    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];

    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];

    //google plus login button

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self

               action:@selector(loginOAuth)

     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(170, 200, 40, 40);

    CALayer * d = [button layer];

    [d setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [d setCornerRadius:20];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)loginOAuth {

    UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");

        NSLog(@"User name ---->>>%@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedUsername);

        NSLog(@"User id ------> %@",FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedID);

ViewController1 *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"]; [dvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical]; [self presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in via twitter you can set the root view controller to be ViewController1.

Add this method to the app delegate

```
  - (void)loginSuccess {
          ViewController1 *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
          UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: dvc];
            self.window.rootViewController =nil;
            self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        }
```

You would then call the loginSuccess method on twitter login success like:

```
     UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [delegate loginSuccess];
      }];
```

Comment: no this is not working story board not found object type AppDelegate

Comment: Ok.It's working now But how to back from viewcontroller1 to viewcontroller

Comment: Maybe you need to pushViewController and not presentViewController, I am not totally sure what you are trying to do.